# How to show control's designer on custom design component at design time

Tags: delphi, devexpress, components, designer

I'm building a design component derived from TFrame with a TPanel and a TdxLayoutControl on it. By registering the Frame as a component using Jeroen Pluimers' RegisterFramesAsComponents method (http://wiert.me/2009/07/16/delphi-frames-as-visual-components-dont-forget-your-sprig/) I was able to get to the desired result. 
I would now however like to open the LayoutControl's designer at design time.
I already made a published property for the LayoutControl but I can not seem to find a way to open its designer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your designer running in the Delphi IDE? If not, then you can't. If it is, then you need to simulate the Tools API from your designer.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers Lucky me got THE man to reply :) Thanks for getting back to me. The designer is in fact shown in the IDE and I somehow managed to get it to show. Changes I make with the designer however are not stored to the DFM. Must have something to do with the Layout Control being a sub-component of my component. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure, I've never used the TdxLayoutControl with a designer. You might want to as the DevExpress guys though.